# Count with Aggreate function in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi my actual code is below:

```
Select M.TicketID,M.CreatedMoment, Max(L.StatusChangeMoment)AS StatusChangeTime,
Elapsed_time_in_Hours_Minutes = CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2),DATEDIFF(minute, M.createdmoment, MAX(L.statuschangemoment))/60+(DATEDIFF(minute, M.createdmoment, MAX(L.statuschangemoment)) % 60/100.0))
From XX_MASTER_TICKETS AS M Left Join XX_DETAIL_TICKET_STATUS_LOG AS L
On M.RowID = L.TicketRowID 
Where M.CreatedMoment between '08-23-2014' And '08-26-2014'

Group by M.TicketID,M.CreatedMoment
Order by M.TicketID asc
```

And the Partial Results is this:

```
TicketID    CreatedMoment   StatusChangeTime    Elapsed_time_in_Hours_Minutes
201408231   8/23/14 8:05 AM 8/25/14 11:47 AM    51.42
2014082310  8/23/14 8:19 AM 8/23/14 12:43 PM    4.24
20140823100 8/23/14 8:38 AM 8/24/14 11:15 AM    26.37
20140823101 8/23/14 8:38 AM 8/23/14 11:58 AM    3.2
20140823102 8/23/14 8:38 AM 8/24/14 10:33 AM    25.55
```

Basically the statuschangetime came from aggregate function, and the last column is the difference of the 2nd and 3rd column.

I want to modify the query so the results will look like this:

```
Date          below24Hrs    above24hours
2014-8-23        2              3
```

My problem is i'm getting error when running this code:

```
Select
[below24hrs] = COUNT (Case WHEN (CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2),DATEDIFF(minute, TM.createdmoment, MAX(LG.statuschangemoment))/60+(DATEDIFF(minute, TM.createdmoment, MAX(LG.statuschangemoment)) % 60/100.0))) < 24 THEN 1 END)
From XX_MASTER_TICKETS AS M Left Join XX_DETAIL_TICKET_STATUS_LOG AS L
On M.RowID = L.TicketRowID 
Where M.CreatedMoment between '08-23-2014' And '08-26-2014'

Group by M.TicketID,M.CreatedMoment
Order by M.TicketID asc
```

It says cannot count with the MAX aggregrate function inside the query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use subquery and sum them.

```
select cast(sqry.CreatedMoment as date) as CreatedMoment
    , sum(case when Elapsed_time_in_Hours_Minutes < 24 then 1 else 0 end) as below24Hrs
    , sum(case when Elapsed_time_in_Hours_Minutes > 24 then 1 else 0 end) as above24Hrs
    , sum(case when Elapsed_time_in_Hours_Minutes = 24 then 1 else 0 end) as At24Hrs
from
(
    Select M.TicketID,M.CreatedMoment, Max(L.StatusChangeMoment)AS StatusChangeTime,
    Elapsed_time_in_Hours_Minutes = CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2),DATEDIFF(minute, M.createdmoment, MAX(L.statuschangemoment))/60+(DATEDIFF(minute, M.createdmoment, MAX(L.statuschangemoment)) % 60/100.0))
    From XX_MASTER_TICKETS AS M Left Join XX_DETAIL_TICKET_STATUS_LOG AS L
    On M.RowID = L.TicketRowID 
    Where M.CreatedMoment between '08-23-2014' And '08-26-2014'
    Group by M.TicketID,M.CreatedMoment
    Order by M.TicketID asc
) sqry
group by  cast(CreatedMoment as date)
```